# Resources on BIM 360 Viewer extensions & dashboard creation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I was following the .NET online training playlist on Forge by Augusto Goncalves. This playlist has the "Forge Online Training, April 2021 Day 3 - Viewer extensions & dashboards (.NET)" session missing/private. Does anyone has any resources on this topic?

Also, I'm totally new to Forge. Can you work with Forge using .NET (Visual Studio) without having to learn Node.js and Postman especially for BIM 360?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAa0VvLRtvI&list=PLJbGSvNUq6VAaZL57IzDLvmo5NLdQreDe&ab_channel=PetrBroz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, no need to learn `node.js` and postman. Here are some resources using .NET:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giEvdvtpj44&list=PLJbGSvNUq6VAaZL57IzDLvmo5NLdQreDe&index=4
- https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/net_3legged
- https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/netcore_3legged

The Postman steps are helping understand how to consume API calls to the Forge service, but it's unnecessary.